# Show that the plane $\{su+tv\mid s,t \in\Bbb R\}$ through the origin in $\Bbb R^3$ is equal to the null space of some element of $(\Bbb R^3)^{*}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

> Let $\{u,v\}$ be a linearly independent set in $\Bbb R^3$.  Show that the plane $\{su+tv\mid s,t \in\Bbb R\}$ through the origin in $\Bbb R^3$ is equal to the null space of some element of $(\Bbb R^3)^{*}$. (Where $(R^3)^*$ is the dual space of $R^3$).

Can we define a linear functional, say $L:R^3 \rightarrow R^2$?

Comment: You can think of this from a geometric perspective. Can you think of a 3x3 matrix which sends the elements of that plane to $0$ ?

Comment: Why are you posting the same question that you asked just a few days ago (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608801/show-that-the-plane-sutvs-t-in-bbb-r-in-bbb-r3-is-equal-to-the-null#comment7418063_3608801)?

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I am aware of that. I just want to ask if I can define a different mapping.

Comment: You could have done that by updating your old question and requesting another answer, rather than littering this site with the same question over and over.  And in the comments under your old question, two users including me gave you a hint that is basically the same as the answer to the answer by  zugzug in this new thread.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I didn't know that. But does that mean I can only mark one as an answer? I feel this is not fair to the old contributor.

Comment: So what?  There are other questions out there with multiple answers.  Nobody really cares which answer you choose to accept.  Almost nobody will complain that you choose to accept one answer over another.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I see.

Comment: And to tell you this, there exists exactly one linear functional $L:\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$ (***up to scalar multiple***) that does the job.  So, the answers you obtained in both the old and the new questions are basically the same answer (they may differ only by a scalar multiple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear functionals will be mappings $L:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$. A plane is generated by two linearly independent vectors, in this case $u$ and $v$. We observe that $u\times v$ is orthogonal to the plane. Hence, for any $x\in P$, where $P$ is the plane, we have 
$$
(u\times v) \cdot x =0.
$$
In order to write this as $Ax=0$, make $A$ a $1\times 3$ matrix where the row is just $u\times v$ (or any constant multiple).